# uable to set layout of a view after adding it in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added a view into WebView , but the problem is after adding a view using webView.addView(myview) the layout of the myview resides on the top of the screen though i have set android:layout_gravity="bottom" in myviews's layout resource file.

so far i have tired following things

myview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"          
>

<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/mc_track_icon"
>

</ImageView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

i tried the relative layout too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


>

<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/mc_track_icon"


>

</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Even i have tried to set the layout explicitly in code also

```
webView.add(myView,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.BOTTOM));
```

But the ImageView is visible on the top left corner only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a Relative layout would be better.Then in the yourlayout.xml  add

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
```

Comment: i tried your approach but no effect after adding it in a WebView , i have edited the post